# Client Server communication opc ua

Tags: python, client-server, opc-ua

I am new to opcua and I have been trying to do communication in the following way:

Server imports xml --> client reads a value(using get_node) --> based on the value, client sends request to server --> Server responds to the request --> Client receives the response.

I have completed the part until the client reads the value. I am now trying to send a request to the server.
But I am unable to understand which method to I use?

I have seen the source code and I can see send_request() method. But I cannot get how to send the request.

Also once I send the request, how would the server respond to it? Please guide me through this or point me to an example.

My client and server look like this:

server.py

```
from opcua import Server
from opcua.ua.uatypes import NodeId, NumericNodeId
from opcua import ua

server = Server()
server.import_xml("Opc.Ua.Di.NodeSet2.xml");
server.import_xml("final.xml");
server.set_endpoint("opc.tcp://localhost:4840/MyServer");
server.set_server_name("MyServer");

MyServerNameSpace = server.get_namespace_index("urn:freeopcua:python:server");
server.start();
```

client.py

```
from opcua import Client
from opcua import ua
from opcua.ua import StringNodeId

client = Client("opc.tcp://localhost:4840");

client.connect_socket();
client.create_session();
client.activate_session(username=None, password=None, certificate=None);


objects = client.get_objects_node();
xx = client.get_node(StringNodeId("i40.io/PrmInst/Temp_1",3));
tempval = xx.get_value();

if tempval < 20 :
#here i want to write the request code
```

Answer (score 0):

can u bit more precise on request code. If its status code that you are after, then
use

```
tempval = xx.get_data_value()
if tempval.Value.Value < 20:
   status = tempval.StatusCode.name # eg: Good/Bad etc..
   message= tempval.StatusCode.doc
```

Try to use get_data_value() which gives you much more info.From there on you can pull out the details that u are after.